# For Loop - Iterator increasing by 1

Tags: python, for-loop

I've been learning Python but I come from a background of Java and in Java, you can set the value that the iterator increases or decreases in each run through the loop. For example, you can say `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 2)` so that the iterator increases by two each time.

From what I've seen so far in Python tutorials, the for loop is unchanging and iterates through each integer from a beginning value to an end value, increasing by one each time. Is there a way to manipulate the Python for loop to set your own increase/decrease value for the iterator?

Comment: "the for loop is unchanging and iterates through each integer from a beginning value to an end value, increasing by one each time." No; it doesn't "iterate through integers" at all. It iterates through the **sequence** that you give to it. `range` is **not part of** the syntax of the `for` loop. It is **just one way** to create a sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following to achieve the same in python:

```
>>> range(1, 10, 2)
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

[See documentation on `range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

You code will therefore be

```
for i in range(0, 10, 2):
    # do_stuff()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `for` loop to iterate over an index in Python, usually you construct a `range` object.

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
# 0, 1, ..., 9
```

`range` has a constructor that takes three arguments, start, stop and step.

```
for i in range(0, 10, 2):
    print(i)
# 0, 2, ..., 8
```

But usually you just iterate over the items in objects rather than indices.

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for element in lst:
    print(element)
# 0, 1, 2, 3
```

However, if your object supports slicing (as lists do), it is easy to get every other member.

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for element in lst[::2]: 
    print(element)
# 0, 2
```

Google "list slicing in Python" if you'd like more information on this syntax.